# How to print conditional fields in PPFA code

Tags: mainframe, zos, afp

How do I print a conditional field using PPFA code. When a value is an 'X' then I'd like to print it. However, if the 'X' is not present then I'd like to print an image. Here is my code:

```
LAYOUT C'mylayout' BODY
  POSITION .25  in ABSOLUTE .25 in
  FONT TIMES
  OVERLAY MYTEMPOVER  8.5 in 11.0 in;
  FIELD START  1 LENGTH 60
  POSITION 2.0  in 1.6  in;
```

Where it has `FIELD START  1 LENGTH 60` that will print the given text at that location. But based on the value I want to print either the given text or an image. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer from the AFP-L list:

I would create two `PAGEFORMATS`, one with LAYOUT for TEXT and one with LAYOUT for IMAGE. With `CONDITION` you can jump between the Pageformats (where Copygroup is always 'NULL')

If you work in a z/OS environment, be careful of 'JES Blanc Truncation'.
That means in one sentence:

- if there is a X in the data, condition is true
- if there is nothing in the data, condition doesn't work and is always wrong (nothing happens)
  In this case you must create a Condition which is always true. I call it a Dummy-Condition.

PPFA sample syntax:

```
CONDITION TEST start 1 length 1 
when eq 'X' NULL PAGEFORMAT PRTTXT
when ge x'00' NULL PAGEFORMAT PRTIMAGE;
```

You must copy this `CONDITION` into both `PAGEFORMATS` after `LAYOUT` command.
Blanc truncation is a difficult problem on z/OS.

In this sample, the `PAGEFORMAT` named `PRTTXT` contains all the formatting and printing directives when the condition is true, and the other called `PRTIMAGE` contains every directive needed to print the image.

HTH

Comment: Wow thank you for this answer. I will try it out.